# MongoDB + Rails Error: Command find requires authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm unable to run commands on MongoDB that has access control enabled from a Rails 6 app.

Here's the error I get:

```
Mongo::Error::OperationFailure (command find requires authentication (13) (on localhost:27017, modern retry, attempt 1))
```

This is my `mongoid.yml`

```
staging:
  clients:
    default:
      database: mydb_staging
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      user: 'julien'
      password: 'mypass'
      auth_source: admin
      auth_mech: :scram
      options:
```

I can connect and authenticate in mongo from the command line and i can connect to it and authenticate remotely through Robomongo.

here are the users i've created:

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.auth('julien', 'mypass')
1
> db.getUsers()
[
    {
        "_id" : "admin.julien",
        "userId" : UUID("3444564f-7dcd-4283-8fb1-ce4f122ed9b8"),
        "user" : "julien",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
            {
                "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                "db" : "admin"
            },
            {
                "role" : "root",
                "db" : "admin"
            },
            {
                "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase",
                "db" : "admin"
            }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
            "SCRAM-SHA-1",
            "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
    }
]
```

I've even created a user with the same credentials in the specific db for the Rails app:

```
> use mydb_staging
switched to db mydb_staging
> db.getUsers()
[
    {
        "_id" : "mydb_staging.julien",
        "userId" : UUID("dc2d8ab6-4f01-4568-be9d-6486283aea14"),
        "user" : "julien",
        "db" : "mydb_staging",
        "roles" : [
            {
                "role" : "readWrite",
                "db" : "mydb_staging"
            }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
            "SCRAM-SHA-1",
            "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
    }
]
```

More details:

```
$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v4.2.8
git version: 43d25964249164d76d5e04dd6cf38f6111e21f5f
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1804
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

Gems versions:

- rails (6.0.3.2)
- mongo (2.12.1)
- mongoid (7.1.2)

Why can't I run commands through Rails and how do I fix this?

**EDIT**

Here's an example from the rails console:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rails console
Loading staging environment (Rails 6.0.3.2)
irb(main):001:0> User.count
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
Mongo::Error::OperationFailure (command count requires authentication (13) (on localhost:27017, modern retry, attempt 1))
```

Comment: Can we see the code that generates the error?

Comment: @Joe any code that uses the DB causes the error, even a simple `User.count`. All the code runs fine on my local env where the DB's access control is disabled.

Comment: Can you try to move 'auth_source' to under options?

Comment: holy molly you're right, there's two `options` key in that config file and i had all the authentication in the wrong one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Nek`'s comment pointed me in the right direction, if you look at the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-configuration/) for the `mongoid.yml` file, you will notice that there are **two** `options` sections, i had to move the authentication part inside one of them, the correct config looks like this:

```
staging:
  clients:
    default:
      database: mydb_staging
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        user: 'julien'
        password: 'mypass'
        auth_source: admin
        auth_mech: :scram
```